# Regarding quick selection function

Tags: javascript

first of all thank you for help!
My issue is I'm trying to find kth largest but some of testcases are failing. If argument is [1,1,1] and k = 1. It will hit base case which is undefined. I'm not sure why it's hitting base case. Again, thank you so much! let me know if you guys need more info!

```js
function kth_largest_in_an_array(numbers, k) {
    return quickSort3(numbers, k, 0, numbers.length-1);
}

const quickSort3 = (numbers, k, start, end) => {
    if (start >= end) {
        console.log('base case')
        return;
    }
    
    //remember random index
    console.log('before: ', numbers)
    let randomIdx =  Math.floor(start + Math.random() * (end - start));
    let partitionedIdx = partition(numbers, start, end, randomIdx);
    console.log('randomIdx: ',randomIdx)
    console.log('partitionedIdx: ',partitionedIdx)
    console.log('start: ', start, 'end: ', end)
    console.log(numbers.slice(start, end+1))
    console.log(numbers)
    console.log('number.length: ',numbers.length)
    //numbers.length = 5, 5-2 == 3
    // console.log('numbers.length - k: ', numbers.length - k)
    if (numbers.length - k === partitionedIdx) {
        console.log('imin: ', numbers[partitionedIdx])
        return numbers[partitionedIdx];
    }
    else if (partitionedIdx < numbers.length - k) {
        return quickSort3(numbers, k, partitionedIdx+1, end);
    }
    else {
        return quickSort3(numbers, k, start, partitionedIdx-1)
    }
}

const partition = (numbers, start, end, randomIdx) => {

    [numbers[start], numbers[randomIdx]] = [numbers[randomIdx], numbers[start]];
    let pivot = numbers[start];
    
    let i = start;
    for (let j = i+1; j<=end; j++) {
        if (pivot > numbers[j]) {
            i++
            [numbers[i], numbers[j]] = [numbers[j], numbers[i]];
        }
    }
    [numbers[start], numbers[i]] = [numbers[i], numbers[start]];
    
    return i;
}
console.log(kth_largest_in_an_array([1,1,1], 1))
// console.log(kth_largest_in_an_array([4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4], 2))
// console.log(kth_largest_in_an_array([5, 1, 10, 3, 2], 2))
```

Comment: There is a good article here (assuming the ask is to also use a quicksort) https://www.baeldung.com/java-kth-largest-element, I realize it is in `java` but a translate to `JavaScript` should be simple enough

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
const t = (arr, kth) => {
  const a = arr.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  return a[kth];
}

console.log(t([1,1,1], 1))
console.log(t([4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4], 2))
console.log(t([5, 1, 10, 3, 2], 2))
```

Comment: @biberty I want to solve with quick selection.

Comment: Yes I did figure that, I posted a link to a good article. That should put you on the right track